# how to avoid performance hit for missing stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

i am serving a static .html page to an iOS app with a uiwebview, and ~50% of the time, there will be a local .css file in the iOS app bundle which visually enhances the content of the served .html file. however, the other ~50% of the time, this .css file will simply not be there at all.

my concern is that this will delay the loading and display of the whole .html page, as it searches for the (missing) .css file which is referred to in the head, like so:

```
<link rel=stylesheet href=whatever.css>
```

are there any techniques that could be used to circumnavigate this issue? perhaps something related to javascript onerror would be useful, just to tell the page not to waste too much time looking, since if the file is there, it will be local, and available ~immediately.

thanks!

Comment: Why does this stylesheet not appear 50% of the time? Is it because of different versions of the iOS app?

Comment: If you take a look at http://pieisgood.org/test/script-link-events/ you can see that _onerror_ of `<link>` is supported from `iOS 6.0.0 (WebKit 536.26)`

Comment: Isn't CSS suppose to be loaded asynchronously? It shouldn't delay the page load/render.

Comment: @BoltClock kind of -- we have an sdk which is in use by multiple developers, and including the .css file is an optional enhancement.

Comment: @PaulS. that's a good link, thank you! still not sure how/if we should use onerror though...

Comment: @Vatev perhaps? though according to this http://www.guypo.com/technical/eliminating-the-css-bottleneck/, linked css is NOT naturally async, but can be made so in webkit by including it in the body, instead of the head. any other thoughts guys?

Comment: It's an app, so you have more control than a normal webpage, right? How about creating an empty `whatever.css` in the instance it's not found at runtime, or setting some flag that prevents the `<link>` being created in subsequent pages?